# Use of SSL Cert results in ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE on ubuntu with apache2

Tags: apache, ssl

Tried to use the ssl cert and key I got from my provider but it's not working out. When I want to connect to my site I get an `ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE` in Google Chrome.

[image]

Here is my Apache Config for the website.

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName example.com
            ServerAlias *.example.com

            ServerAdmin me@example.com
            DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public

            Redirect "/" "https://example.com/"

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com.error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com.access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>

    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
            <VirtualHost *:443>
                    ServerName example.com
                    ServerAlias *.example.com

                    ServerAdmin me@example.com
                    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public

                    SSLEngine on

                    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.crt
                    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/private/example.com.key

                    <Directory /var/www/example.com/>
                            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                            AllowOverride All
                            Order allow,deny
                            allow from all
                            <Limit POST PUT DELETE>
                                    Require all granted
                            </Limit>
                    </Directory>

                    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com.error.log
                    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com.access.log combined
            </VirtualHost>
    </IfModule>
```

I also ensured that the firewall allowes https connections.

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: if you are not afraid to show us that the site is named thomasventurini.com, why there is example.com in config?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to enable ssl module. Check port 443 is listening (netstat -an | grep 443)

Comment: @Andra good point ;)

Comment: @EugèneAdell This is what I get from netstat `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443    0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so strangely ssl/https/port 443 was indeed NOT enabled on my server. Don't know why everything tells me that https is enabled but here is how I could solve it for me.

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```