# My setup for https on my Ubuntu server using Nginx with certbot fails with ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, https, certbot

My goal is to have Nginx return it's example welcome page while using https.

I used certbot to create the certificates with the following command:
`certbot --nginx -d api.example.com`

In my `/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-example-server.conf`
I have the following block:

```
server {
       listen      443 ssl;
       server_name api.example.com
       ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/cert.pem;
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/privkey.pem;
       include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
}
```

the `include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;` includes the following:

```
ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:1m;
ssl_session_timeout 1440m;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers: "<Lots of cyphers>"
```

`ufw status verbose` returns:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # Open all to access Nginx port 443
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # Open access Nginx port 80
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # Open access OpenSSH port 22
8000                       DENY IN     Anywhere                  
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)              # Open all to access Nginx port 443
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)              # Open access Nginx port 80
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)              # Open access OpenSSH port 22
8000 (v6)                  DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)
```

If I visit https://api.example.com (not the real url, of course) it responds with `ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE`.

`/var/log/nginx/access.log` and `/var/log/nginx/error.log` both don't log anything concerning the `ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE`.

I tried to find my `ufw` log files, but there aren't any. I tried to find them as described in here: `https://serverfault.com/a/516840`

I have looked all over for tips and followed a few tutorials. Everything results in the same response. I can succesfully reach the Nginx welcome page over http though.

Help is very welcome! Even if it's only a better way to debug this thing.

Answer (score 4):

This fixed it: `sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT`

As posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50373181/6565435

Answer (score 0):

Necrones are here.

If someone has the same issue, try to check your `ip route`.
Maybe some interfaces "covers" necessary ip adresses. For example, it could be some docker-compose bridges (name of the interface will be like "br-...").

To check if it so, you can do next steps:

1. `systemctl disable docker` - to disable docker service autostart.
2. reboot
3. check `ip route` again. If some bridges do not appear there now, they were tied with docker service.
   Why?
   Somethimes it happens when you did use docker-compose: it creates a lot of virtual net interfaces.